# MQL4 how to get if a price hits an object?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, mql4, forex

How to get if a price hits an object? Lets say, the object is a pitchfork, or trendline, manually drawn. I guess, it should start this way:

`if(Bid==?)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not a bad guess

Let's go through the story step by step.

### [image: GUI-objects]

## A price:   <sub>. . . which one ?</sub>

**`{ Ask, Bid }`** - while most of Technical Analyses are derived from a **`Bid`**-based perspective, one must have experienced that certain XTO-events are related to **`Ask`** price levels.

For the sake of simplicity, let's keep the `Bid` as the only price to work with, while the framework could be extended to have the complete `PriceDOMAIN` duality under the hood.

### A TimeFrame:  <sub>. . . which one ?</sub>

Sounds strange? Well, not so surprising, MetaTrader Terminal 4 graphics does **not** allow one to place GUI-objects arbitrarily. While this need not be realised from the very start, one will fail if trying to place a GUI-object onto an exact `TimeDOMAIN` coordinate. The `PriceDOMAIN` coordinates are not so restricted, but additional surprises appear if one of the GUI-object definition points fall into far or near future, but the respective Market-session administratively closes ( a FRI/MON-gap, a midnight-gap, DE.30/DAX post-Market/pre-Market-gap etc. ) before the real-time reaches the "future" point in time. Such objects become distorted if not completely jumped-off-the screen.

Besides this the concept of TimeFrames introduces another question -- does the condition **`if(Bid....)`** that we are just to assemble -- hold and yields the very same result in `D1`, `H4`, `H1`, `M5` and `M1`? While this seems to be simply decided in `PriceDOMAIN` ( and it is not in practice, another bad surprise is waiting behind the corner ) it is quite sure, that `TimeDOMAIN` coordinates of **when** a condition constellation was met do and will differ, depending on TimeFrame, on which the GUI-object is placed and challenged with the algorithm.

Simply put, while GUI-objects are painted "**continuous**", they are not. Their internal representation in `MQL4` ecosystem is discrete, so one shall rather forget all the algebra of linear and quadratic objects.

The best would be to imagine a GUI-object as an ordered set of `[x-TimeDOMAIN, y-PriceDOMAIN]` coordinates -- **yes, an ordered set of points**, where the **`x`** ( surprising or not ) is visually the most misleading - the middle of the bar representation is not the "middle" of the real-flow of time, but the administrative Market wall-clock - the time of the beginning of the `Bar`.

### How to handle all these glitches and guess the value(s)?

To have at least some help from MQL4 side, there are a few utility functions for this:

```
int     ObjectGetShiftByValue( string   anObjectNAME,      // ...
                               double   aTargetPriceLEVEL  // a price to reach
                               )
```

plus

```
double  ObjectGetValueByShift( string   anObjectNAME,      // guess what
                               int      aShiftInTimeDOMAIN // bar index 
                               )
```

One will have a lot of troubles saved by this pair of handy functions, but still will have to implement a carefull handling of weekend/market-gaps ( the bars-space that is "now" visible, but will "disappear" in some near future and dare one to have GUI-objects with a definition point "forgotten" right out there ... ).

---

### Last, but not least ... A danger of **`==`** ... not only in `if(Bid...)`
 <sub>( An Orwellish "We are all equal, but some of us are more equal... " )</sub>

Guess everyone, who has spent some time with Custom Indicator construction, has also met the dark side of IEEE-float numerical (im)**precision**. Smoothing and deep convolution computations introduce this phenomenon sooner than later and a first-aid `( double-precision float )` does not eradicate the principal loss of numerical precision these representations of non-integer values simply have to suffer from.

This said, one shall rather knowingly work with imprecise numbers and replace binary strict equality tests ( **`==`** ), that are failing to yield fair answers on noisy un-precise numbers, and rather use this glitch:

```
#define EQUALITY_TOLERANCE  0.000005
  if (  EQUALITY_TOLERANCE > MathAbs( Bid - aTargetPRICE ) )
  {  // EQUAL

   }
  else
  {

   }
```

Certainly, the same logic applies to `PriceDOMAIN` cross-testing and other derived `{ >= | > | < | <= | != }` conditions.

[image]